# How to pass value in a link_to inside a mail of Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is the way I am approving certain events in my site.
The idea is:
With every new event, an email is send to "admin@example.com". The email contains certain stuff and a link to a method that changes the 'approved' boolean.
Everything works apart from the url generated in the email.
It generates, http://example.com/approve_event . And I get the error 'Could not find an event with id nil'

How should I do to get a url that points to something like http://example.com/approve_event?=23

AdminNotifier

```
  def approve_event(event)
    @event = event    
    mail(:to => "admin@example.com", :subject => "Event pending of approval")
  end
```

email view html

```
  = link_to "Approve", approve_event_url(:id=> @event.id)
```

EventController

```
 def approved
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
   @event.approved = true
   @event.save
 end
```

Comment: how are you retrieving `@event` in the mailer?

Comment: I call the mailer from the EventController. AdminMailer.approve_event(@event).deliver

Shall I have in the mailer method something like: @event = Event.find(params[:id])

Comment: You're using `@event`in the view, and for that to work you need to define the `@event` variable in the mailer. Take a look at the `approve_event` method and check if you're using a valid event object.

Comment: Yeah!! The object I was passing did not have id yet. Thanks guys, you are great!

Comment: Cool! I just added this as an answer so you can mark it and close the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `@event` variable is defined correctly in the mailer method (`approve_event` in this case), to make sure that it will be available in the view.

[More info on the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)